# Reactjs/Angularjs environment setup in windows 10

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, web-applications, visual-studio-code, client-side

Windows 10:
I have installed Node, NPM, visual studio code.
Now I would like to create apps and play with Reactjs/AngularJs + HTML + Bootstrap.

Can I just create apps in Reactjs/Angularjs with simple notepad?

Please provide some guidance, as I am newbie to Reactjs/Angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app

cd my-app
npm start
```

Use atom as your IDE its better than Visual Studio Code

No you can not just do it in simple notepad

Comment: :use this its better than npm: https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/install/#mac-stable